# Resource folder duplicated automatically in android

Tags: android, resources, r.java-file, generated

I just added a new xml file to my android project and started getting the error 'R cannot be resolved to a 
 variable'. There are lot of questions and answers when I google it and also in stack overflow. When I clean the project, a new empty folder is automatically generated having the same name as my resource folder('res').

Also I found no errors in my xml files. Also I found that the generated java files folder is empty. I am getting the same error for all the projects in eclipse.

What could be the problem?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an image file who's name contains characters that are not allowed. I just renamed the image.

Answer (score 0):

`R cannot be resolved to a variable` appears when something's wrong either with your xml resource, layout files or the Manifest file. 
Try to add your xml files one by one to this newly generated res folder (to find out which one is causing the problem) and try if it helps.

Comment: I deleted the xml file which caused the error and the problem persists.

Comment: Check if `R.java` haven't been imported into your class. If so, delete it, clean up the project and try to run it again.

Comment: It is not imported. I am getting the same error for all the projects in eclipse now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details if you want a clear answer, at least the code of your XML file. This error comes most of the time from a malformed or incorrect XML file. Check also if the strings, drawables or whatever you are calling in the XML file are well declared in the project resources.